# HighCharts / HighStock newly added series have problem with shared tooltips and mouse hover effect

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I draw a default OHLC chart. Then add a simple scatter series to it.
I set chart level config to share tooltips.
tooltip: { shared: true }.

But two series won't share tooltips at all.

Another big problem is that I cannot control the mouse hover effect on the new series. If you try the demo below, after clicking the AddSeries button at the bottom, the newly added series will be highlighted on mouse hover. I try to remove the mouse over effect and control it with the lineWidthPlus parameter, but there is no effect on the newly added series. Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
    "hover": {
      "enabled": false
    },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2t7fg9rc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about adding the line series instead of scatter? I cannot see the hover issue that you described while using the line series.

```
  var seriesConfig = {
    "data": [
      [1557322200000, 50.72],
      [1566999000000, 51.03],
      [1577197800000, 70.73],
      [1588858200000, 75.93],
      [1601040600000, 108.43],
      [1620394200000, 130.85]
    ],
    "type": "line",
    "id": "Indicator",
    "name": "Indicator",
    "yAxis": 0,
    "color": "rgb(256,0,0,0.75)",
    "marker": {
      enabled: true,
      "symbol": "circle",
      "radius": "2"
    },
    "showInNavigator": false,
    "showInLegend": true,
    "states": {
      "inactive": {
        "opacity": 1
      },
      "hover": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "stickyTracking": false
    }
  };
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hfzwd8Lc/